# Is there a "goto" statement in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, goto

Is there a "goto" statement in Bash?

I know it is considered bad practice, but I need specifically a "goto".

Comment: No, there's not `goto` in bash (at least it says `command not found` for me). Why? Chances are there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You never need goto, at worst you need more practice with other control flow tools.

Comment: He may have his reasons. I found this question because I want a `goto` statement to skip over a lot of code for debugging a large script without waiting an hour for various unrelated tasks to complete. I'd certainly not use a `goto` in the production code, but for debugging my code, it'd make my life infinitely easier, and it'd be easier to spot when it came to remove it.

Comment: @delnan But having no goto can make some things more complicated. There indeed are use cases.

Comment: It would help if you would specify your reason for needing it. If it is for exception handling, create a function with an exit statement in it and call that function... Also, if you have a large script with lots of debugging statements, if would be much more readable with an if statement or split it up into multiple functions. Its not a good idea to create Bash scripts that are hundreds of lines long without splitting it up into mutiple functions, just like any other programming language.

Comment: @KarlNicoll I also want it for debugging purpose. We won't care best practises while debugging the code.

Comment: I'm sick of this goto myth!  There's nothing wrong with goto!  Everything you write eventually becomes goto. In assembler, there is only goto.  A good reason to use goto in higher programming languages is for example jumping out of nested loops in a clean and readable way.

Comment: @alexc Sorry, but no - jumping out of nested loops is exactly (one of) the reasons so many people hate goto! There are reasonable use cases for it, but that isn't one of them, and even if it was, it would only be a reason to have multi-level continue statements; not a generalized goto. Still, you're right - and I agree with your conclusion, even if not your example.

Comment: I have the worst reason of all - porting windows cmd files more-or-less 1:1 to bash. They usually have little to zero structuring except on the "goto" level...

Comment: "Avoid goto" is a great rule.  Like any rule, it should be learned in three phases.  First: follow the rule until it's second nature.  Second, learn to understand the reasons for the rule.  Third, learn good exceptions to the rule, based on a comprehensive understanding of how to follow the rule and the reasons for the rule.  Avoid skipping steps above, which would be like using "goto".  ;-)

Comment: The shell used to have a `goto` command.  The `:` command which used to make a label is a rudiment of this.  However, no such feature remains today.

Comment: I think we've discovered the problem. GOTO has been omitted from the shell. Who can we get to fix this oversight?

Comment: C shell has a goto:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh

Comment: goto is 'considered harmful' but if you do use it do not have multiple ones which cross the lines of other gogo commands.  i.e. don't have a gogo which jumps from line 1 to 5 and then another one that jumps to 3.  This causes nightmare spaghetti.  Also, only jumping forward is another good giudeline.

Comment: @StefanHegny That's presumably because of how eager `%expansion%` is in the DOS/Windows command.com/cmd.exe language; read all about it in [`help set`](https://gist.github.com/SamB/957ae854d2f58d79e03da25d8a42bf22).

Comment: Bash is a scripting language, and (along with other shell langs) the only language that literally everyone uses it more on a REPL than in files. This makes code style rules in Bash fundamentally different from all other (non-shell) langs. For example, goto is usually an antipattern in other languages because it leads to inconsistent states, but in Bash, you often come to a case where there're overwhelmingly more stateless lines than stateful (variable-assigning) lines. On the other hand, filesystem-manipulating lines are stateful in another manner, which happens regardless whether goto is used

Comment: The main difference is that Bash is (usually) used by a human, just to execute a bunch of commands quickly without typing so much. Nobody runs an unattended server in Bash. This means if there are any unexpected states, the human should be able to repair it immediately; in particular, scripts are usually just used by the person who wrote the script, which means he knows how to debug it. Especially with `set -x` turned on.
Also, error recovery is quite handy when there is `set -e`.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel how do you define "runs in an unattended server"? it is very normal to have a Bash script that acts as an entrypoint to a server image, even a complex one, which is *usually* fine as long as it works and it is able to start the main process. Or do you mean your Bash script is actually part of the main loop, such that it runs even after the server started and so bugs in the Bash script could lead to divergent server behavior that cannot be immediately spotted without careful testing (in contrast to running it once)?

Comment: that said, I think it is pretty obvious that you shouldn't use `goto` in an unattended script (as much as you shouldn't use `goto` in a C program that needs to be maintained for more than a few hours). And `goto` is arguably much less harmful than lack of `set -euo pipefail` by default.

Comment: @SOFe — All of the above. People develop and run complete server applications in Bash. Now I am _**not endorsing**_ the development of server apps in Bash, but believing that no one done does is naive, and asserting to people on a site like this that they don't — when it is impossible for you to know they don't — is irresponsible.  Which is why I commented.

Comment: @SOFe — I will also challenge your assertions regarding `goto` — there is nothing about responsible use of `goto` that is problematic. Thinking otherwise is evidence of  uncritically accepting conventional wisdom arising from the regrettably-named anti-`goto` essay that, according to its author _(verbatim quote here_): _"in later years would be most frequently referenced, regrettably, however, often by authors who had seen no more of it than its title."_.  No, server apps can be _**more robust and diagnosable**_ when `goto` is used: https://github.com/mikeschinkel/goto-considered-beneficial

Comment: Related tale for the "considered harmful" fundamentalists: When I studied beginner music composition & unknowingly "modulated to the dominant" in an assignment my teacher criticised it. He asked "can you explain what you did there?" (answer: "no, but it sounds cool"). He then said: Beethoven's music "breaks the rules" everywhere, but gets away with it because he studied the rules so well he knew how to break them properly. Competent devs using "goto" in code is the same - ask the Linux kernel devs https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/154980 - or Socrates: "ἓν οἶδα ὅτι οὐδὲν οἶδα"

Answer (score 104, accepted):

No, there is not; see [§3.2.4 "Compound Commands" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands) for information about the control structures that *do* exist. In particular, note the mention of `break` and `continue`, which aren't as flexible as `goto`, but are more flexible in Bash than in some languages, and may help you achieve what you want. (Whatever it is that you want . . .)

Comment: Could you expand on "more flexible in Bash than in some languages"?

Comment: @user239558: Some languages only allow you to `break` or `continue` from the innermost loop, whereas Bash lets you specify how many levels of loop to jump. (And even of languages that allow you to `break` or `continue` from arbitrary loops, most require that to be expressed statically -- e.g., `break foo;` will break out of the loop labeled `foo` -- whereas in Bash it's expressed dynamically -- e.g., `break "$foo"` will break out of `$foo` loops.)

Comment: I'd recommend defining functions with the needed features and caling them from other parts of the code.

Comment: @ruakh Actually, many languages allow `break LABEL_NAME;`, rather than Bash's disgusting `break INTEGER;`.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick: Yes, I mentioned that in the comment that you're replying to.

Comment: @ruakh _Oh._. My bad.

Answer (score 178):

No. But, if you are using it to skip part of a large script for debugging (see Karl Nicoll's comment), then if false could be a good workaround.

```bash
# ... Code I want to run here ...

if false; then

# ... Code I want to skip here ...

fi

# ... I want to resume here ...
```

The difficulty comes in when it's time to rip out your debugging code.  The "if false" construct is pretty straightforward and memorable, but how do you find the matching fi?  If your editor allows you to block indent, you could indent the skipped block (then you'll want to put it back when you're done).  Or a comment on the fi line, but it would have to be something you'll remember, which I suspect will be very programmer-dependent.

Comment: Yes `false` is always available. But if you have a block of code you don't want to execute, just comment it out. Or delete it (and look in your source control system if you need to recover it later).

Comment: If ithe block of code is too long to tediously comment out one line at a time, see these tricks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947897/block-comments-in-a-shell-script  However, these don't help a text editor match the beginning to the end, either, so they're not much of an improvement.

Comment: "if false" is often far better than commenting out code, because it ensures that the enclosed code continues to be legal code.  The best excuse for commenting out code is when it really needs to be deleted, but there's something that needs to be remembered -- so it's just a comment, and no longer "code".

Comment: I use the comment '#if false;'.  That way I can just search for that and find both the beginning and end of the debug removal section.

Comment: This answer should not be upvoted since it doesn't respond to the OP's question in any way.

Comment: Ripping out that `if false` bit is as easy as changing it to `if true`. Not as clean as properly removing it, of course, but it's simple enough.

Comment: "not sure if "false" is always available, for me it is in /bin/false" bash has its own `false` command that does not trigger the OS /bin/false. So since OP is referring to Bash, `false` is always available even in those "distroless" docker images that do not have /bin/false.

Answer (score 84):

It indeed may be useful for some debug or demonstration needs.

I found that Bob Copeland solution http://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/ elegant:

```
#!/bin/bash
# include this boilerplate
function jumpto
{
    label=$1
    cmd=$(sed -n "/$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
    eval "$cmd"
    exit
}

start=${1:-"start"}

jumpto $start

start:
# your script goes here...
x=100
jumpto foo

mid:
x=101
echo "This is not printed!"

foo:
x=${x:-10}
echo x is $x
```

results in:

```
$ ./test.sh
x is 100
$ ./test.sh foo
x is 10
$ ./test.sh mid
This is not printed!
x is 101
```

Comment: "My quest to make bash look like assembly language draws ever nearer to completion." - Wow. Just, wow.

Comment: the only thing I'd change is make it so that labels start like so `: start:` so that they aren't syntax errors.

Comment: I love this. Suddenly debugging got way faster.

Comment: Would be better if you did that:

    cmd=$(sed -n "/#$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')

with labels starting as:

    #start: => this would prevent script errors

Comment: I'm getting segmentation faults. Going to try the suggestions where labels are commented out. Update: I think it's trying execute the labels and crashing. Starting the label with a ": " or # as suggested seemed to fix that. Great work, can't wait to try this out.

Comment: Actually this script is written by Robert Copeland not Judy.

Comment: @CloudCho I refer to Judy blogpost... Where you find other copyright? I should edit post to reflect this if it true.

Comment: @Hubbitus ... I went the link (http://bobcopeland.com...) you posted. Isn't the link belonging to Bob Coperland? I thought Judy just made a comment on his website. Please, let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Hm, indeed it most likely my mistake. I have edit post. Thank you.

Comment: `set -x` helps understand what's going on

Comment: **Issues**: 1) Indiscriminately removes all lines ending in a `:`. 2) Treats `label:` anywhere on a line as a label. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872489/5353461) for the resolution.

Comment: @AlexejMagura there is [potential for those errors to be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886065/bash-script-error-catching) and/or mitigated if desired

Comment: In bash, there's always a way.

Comment: It works for me in GNU sed version but not in macOS sed version. A error message: sed: 1: "/:start:/{:a;n;p;ba};": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately, I have no MacOS now to check.

Answer (score 35):

If you're testing/debugging a bash script, and simply want to skip forwards past one or more sections of code, here is a very simple way to do it that is also very easy to find and remove later (unlike most of the methods described above).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Run this"

cat >/dev/null <<GOTO_1

echo "Don't run this"

GOTO_1

echo "Also run this"

cat >/dev/null <<GOTO_2

echo "Don't run this either"

GOTO_2

echo "Yet more code I want to run"
```

To put your script back to normal, just delete any lines with `GOTO`.

We can also prettify this solution, by adding a `goto` command as an alias:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias goto="cat >/dev/null <<"

goto GOTO_1

echo "Don't run this"

GOTO_1

echo "Run this"

goto GOTO_2

echo "Don't run this either"

GOTO_2

echo "All done"
```

Aliases don't usually work in bash scripts, so we need the `shopt` command to fix that.

If you want to be able to enable/disable your `goto`'s, we need a little bit more:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
if [ -n "$DEBUG" ] ; then
  alias goto="cat >/dev/null <<"
else
  alias goto=":"
fi

goto '#GOTO_1'

echo "Don't run this"

#GOTO1

echo "Run this"

goto '#GOTO_2'

echo "Don't run this either"

#GOTO_2

echo "All done"
```

Then you can do `export DEBUG=TRUE` before running the script.

The labels are comments, so won't cause syntax errors if disable our `goto`'s (by setting `goto` to the '`:`' no-op), but this means we need to quote them in our `goto` statements.

Whenever using any kind of `goto` solution, you need to be careful that the code you're jumping past doesn't set any variables that you rely on later - you may need to move those definitions to the top of your script, or just above one of your `goto` statements.

Comment: Without getting into the good/bad-ness of goto's, Laurence's solution is just cool. You got my vote.

Comment: That's more like a skip-to, an `if(false)` seems to make more sense (to me).

Comment: Quoting the goto "label" also means that the here-doc *is not* expanded/evaluated which saves you from some hard to find bugs (unquoted, it would be subject to: parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, which can all have side-effects). You can also tweak this a little with `alias goto=":<<"` and dispense with `cat` altogether.

Comment: yes, vesperto, you can use an 'if' statement, and I've done that in many scripts, but it gets very messy and is much harder to control and keep track of, especially if you want to change your jump points frequently.

Comment: This is very interesting. You could improve the answer by explaining *why* this works, why the `cat <<` command does the trick.

Comment: @ysap It's not `cat <<`, it's [Bash's](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) [_heredoc_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document): `[n]<<[-]word`\n`here-document`\n`delimiter` the contents of which are `stdin` to `cat` which prints it to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `case` in bash to simulate a goto:

```
#!/bin/bash

case bar in
  foo)
    echo foo
    ;&

  bar)
    echo bar
    ;&

  *)
    echo star
    ;;
esac
```

produces:

```
bar
star
```

Comment: Note that this requires `bash v4.0+`. It is, however, not a general-purpose `goto` but a fall-through option for the `case` statement.

Comment: i think this should be the answer.
i have a genuine need for go to in order to support resume execution of a script, from a given instruction. 
this is, in every way but semantic, goto, and semantics and syntactic sugars are cute, but not strictly necessary. great solution, IMO.

Comment: @nathang, whether it's **the** answer depends on whether your case happens to mesh with the subset of the general case the OP asked about. Unfortunately, the question asks about the general case, making this answer too narrow to be correct. (Whether that question should be _closed_ as too broad for that reason is a different discussion).

Comment: goto is more than selecting. goto feature means to be able to jump to places acording to some conditions, creating even a loop like flow...

Answer (score 18):

Although others have already clarified that there is no direct `goto` equivalent in bash (and provided the closest alternatives such as functions, loops, and break), I would like to illustrate how using a loop plus `break` can simulate a specific type of goto statement.

The situation where I find this the most useful is when I need to return to the beginning of a section of code if certain conditions are not met. In the example below, the while loop will run forever until ping stops dropping packets to a test IP.

```
#!/bin/bash

TestIP="8.8.8.8"

# Loop forever (until break is issued)
while true; do

    # Do a simple test for Internet connectivity
    PacketLoss=$(ping "$TestIP" -c 2 | grep -Eo "[0-9]+% packet loss" | grep -Eo "^[0-9]")

    # Exit the loop if ping is no longer dropping packets
    if [ "$PacketLoss" == 0 ]; then
        echo "Connection restored"
        break
    else
        echo "No connectivity"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 13):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269848/5353461) had the following issues:

- Indiscriminately removes all code lines ending in a `:`
- Treats `label:` anywhere on a line as a label

Here's a fixed ([`shell-check`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) clean and POSIX compatible) version:

---

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# GOTO for bash, based upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269848/5353461
goto() {
  label=$1
  cmd=$(sed -En "/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*$label:[[:space:]]*#/{:a;n;p;ba};" "$0")
  eval "$cmd"
  exit
}

start=${1:-start}
goto "$start"  # GOTO start: by default

#start:#  Comments can occur after labels
echo start
goto end

  # skip: #  Whitespace is allowed
echo this is usually skipped

# end: #
echo end
```

Comment: Once you learn goto, you never need if or for again.

Answer (score 6):

There is one more ability to achieve a desired results: command `trap`. It can be used to clean-up purposes for example.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `goto` in bash.

Here is some dirty workaround using [`trap`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) which jumps only backwards:)

```
#!/bin/bash -e
trap '
echo I am
sleep 1
echo here now.
' EXIT

echo foo
goto trap 2> /dev/null
echo bar
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
foo
I am
here now.
```

This shouldn't be used in that way, but only for educational purposes.  Here is why this works:

`trap` is using exception handling to achieve the change in code flow. 
In this case the `trap` is catching anything that causes the script to EXIT.  The command `goto` doesn't exist, and hence throws an error, which would ordinarily exit the script.  This error is being caught with `trap`, and the `2>/dev/null` hides the error message that would ordinarily be displayed.

This implementation of goto is obviously not reliable, since any non-existent command (or any other error, for that manner), would execute the same trap command.  In particular, you cannot choose which label to go-to.

---

Basically in real scenario you don't need any goto statements, they're redundant as random calls to different places only make your code difficult to understand.

If your code is invoked many times, then consider to use loop and changing its workflow to use `continue` and `break`.

If your code repeats it-self, consider writing the function and calling it as many times as you want.

If your code needs to jump into specific section based on the variable value, then consider using `case` statement.

If you can separate your long code into smaller pieces, consider moving it into separate files and call them from the parent script.

Comment: what's the differences between this form and a normal function?

Comment: @yurenchen - Think of `trap` as using `exception handling` to achieve the change in code flow.  In this case the trap is catching anything that causes the script to `EXIT`, which is triggered by invoking the non-existent command `goto`.  BTW: The argument `goto trap` could be anything, `goto ignored` because it is the `goto` that causes the EXIT, and the `2>/dev/null` hides the error message saying your script is exiting.

Comment: I am having following error: `permission denied: /dev/nul`

Answer (score 3):

I found out a way to do this using functions.

Say, for example, you have 3 choices: `A`, `B`, and `C`. `A` and `B`execute a command, but `C` gives you more info and takes you to the original prompt again. This can be done using functions.

Note that since the line containg `function demoFunction` is just setting up the function, you need to call `demoFunction` after that script so the function will actually run.

You can easily adapt this by writing multiple other functions and calling them if you need to "`GOTO`" another place in your shell script.

```
function demoFunction {
        read -n1 -p "Pick a letter to run a command [A, B, or C for more info] " runCommand

        case $runCommand in
            a|A) printf "\n\tpwd being executed...\n" && pwd;;
            b|B) printf "\n\tls being executed...\n" && ls;;
            c|C) printf "\n\toption A runs pwd, option B runs ls\n" && demoFunction;;
        esac
}

demoFunction
```

Comment: aka infinite recursion. better use `while true` to keep the call stack small, to avoid [segfault](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296641/segmentation-fault-when-calling-a-recursive-bash-function). see also: recursion via [trampoline function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189725/what-is-a-trampoline-function)

Answer (score 3):

This is a small correction of the Judy Schmidt script put up by Hubbbitus.

Putting non-escaped labels in the script was problematic on the machine and caused it to crash. This was easy enough to resolve by adding # to escape the labels. Thanks to Alexej Magura and access_granted for their suggestions.

```
#!/bin/bash
# include this boilerplate
function goto {  
label=$1
cmd=$(sed -n "/$#label#:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
eval "$cmd"
exit
}

start=${1:-"start"}

goto $start

#start#
echo "start"
goto bing

#boom#
echo boom
goto eof

#bang#
echo bang
goto boom

#bing#
echo bing
goto bang

#eof#
echo "the end mother-hugger..."
```

Comment: This copy paste is not working => there is still a jumpto.

Comment: What does that mean?  What's not working?  Could you be more specific?

Comment: Of course I tried the code! I tested under 5 or 6 different conditions before posting all successful. How did the code fail for you, what error message or code?

Comment: Whatever man. I want to help you but you're being really vague and uncommunicative (not to mention insulting with that "did you test it" question). What does "you didn't paste correctly mean"? If you're referring to the "/$#label#:/{:a;n;p;ba};" part, I'm very aware that it's different. I modified it for the new label format (aka #label# vs :label in other answer which was crashing script in some cases). Do you have some valid problem with my answer (like script crash or bad syntax) or did you simply -1 my answer because you thought "I don't know how to cut and paste"?

Comment: `jumpto $start`

Comment: The reason is that it does not add much added values to the precedent answers and it is not working as intended because the function name has been changed in between.

Comment: @thebunnyrules I ran into the same issue as you but [solved it differently](https://superuser.com/a/1353588/398314) **+1 for your solution though!**

Comment: @Alex Paques the main answer was crashing because bash didn't know what to do with tags that begin with : :tag1 :tag2 etc. Adding a # instead of : fixed that. Sorry if you don't think fixing a big bug like this adds anything. And "a non sarcastic" sorry about it crashing on your PC. I did test it quite a bit before posting it but these things are hard to completely test for sometime.

Comment: @AlexisPaques and I changed the incorrect statement you were referring to.  =time to remove the downvote?  **;-)**  Next time just edit as it's very hard for yourself to see a dumb copy-paste error.  Also notified the original author of my solution to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't anyone just use functions directly ? 
BTW functions are easier to deal with than making a new thing

**My style :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Your functions
function1 ()
{
    commands
}

function2 ()
{
    commands
}
    :
    :

functionn ()
{
    commands
}

# Execute 1 to n in order
for i in {1..n}
    do
        function$i
    done

# with conditions
for i in {1..n}
    do
        [ condition$i ] && function$i
    done

# Random order
function1
functionn
function5
    :
    :
function3
```

**Example for above style :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Your functions
function1 ()
{
    echo "Task 1"
}

function2 ()
{
    echo "Task 2"
}

function3 ()
{
    echo "Task 3"
}

function1
function3
function2
```

**Output :**

```
Task 1
Task 3
Task 2
```

**Drawbacks :**

- Script in an organized way.
- Less problems and not prone to errors.
- You can make function inside a existing function.
- Move back and forth without any problems.

Comment: "Why don't anyone just use functions directly ?" If you need to step through and debug an existing script to break it out into functions because it wasn't in the first place :) .

Answer (score 1):

A simple searchable goto for the use of commenting out code blocks when debugging.

```
GOTO=false
if ${GOTO}; then
    echo "GOTO failed"
    ...
fi # End of GOTO
echo "GOTO done"
```

Result is-> GOTO done

Answer (score 0):

My idea for creating something like "goto" is to use `select` with `case` and assign a variable, which I then check in an if statement. Not perfect, but may help in some cases

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

select goto in Ubuntu Debian Quit ; do
    case $goto in
        Ubuntu) { CHOICE="Ubuntu" ; break ; } ;;
        Debian) { CHOICE="Debian" ; break ; } ;;
        Quit)   { echo "Bye" ; exit ; } ;;
        *)      { echo "Invalid selection, please try again..." ; } ;;
    esac
done

if [ "$CHOICE" == "Ubuntu" ]; then
    echo "I'm in Ubuntu"
fi

if [ "$CHOICE" == "Debian" ]; then
    echo "I'm in Debian"
fi
```