# Any way to exit bash script, but not quitting the terminal

Tags: linux, bash

When I use `exit` command in a shell script, the script will terminate the terminal (the prompt). Is there any way to terminate a script and then staying in the terminal?

My script `run.sh` is expected to execute by directly being sourced, or sourced from another script.

EDIT:
To be more specific, there are two scripts `run2.sh` as

```
...
. run.sh
echo "place A"
...
```

and `run.sh` as

```
...
exit
...
```

when I run it by `. run2.sh`, and if it hit `exit` codeline in `run.sh`, I want it to stop to the terminal and stay there. But using `exit`, the whole terminal gets closed.

PS: I have tried to use `return`, but `echo` codeline will still gets executed....

Comment: I really, really, really have to ask: why are you using exit in a sourced script?

Comment: the exit command should not terminate your terminal session/login. if you use `exit 0` to terminate the script after success, when you run your script ex: `./test.sh` you should see the output but your console will remain open.

Comment: You could use the `shell` command, that opens in fact a shell terminal. My own experience however is that this doesn't happen with `exit`. Exit normally gives back the control to the parent script.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. It only kills process (aka the terminal) if called from the top level (globally.) And why would you do that? At the top level, it exits gracefully by itself after completing anyway. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams your comment does little except to make the OP feel bad. It sort of hints that the problem has to do with sourcing the script, but why not just say that instead of making someone feel bad for trying it? After all, it's a kind of subtle point that exec and source run differently in terms of shell. Ah, but I see that five people have joined you in being mean...

Answer (score 383, accepted):

The "problem" really is that you're sourcing and not executing the script. When you source a file, its contents will be executed in the current shell, instead of spawning a subshell. So everything, including exit, will affect the current shell.

Instead of using `exit`, you will want to use `return`.

Comment: Here's another explanation that I found helpful: http://askubuntu.com/a/53179/148337

Comment: Although correct, this is not a great answer. It ignores that the calling script may declare variables or functions that that called script needs access to. Better to explain how to set a return code and then process it in `runs.sh` @ruakh has the better answer to this question.

Comment: What if the function is a nested call? i.e. a calls b, b calls c, c wants to immediately exit a and b.

Comment: Source is almost the same as copy paste. It's better to use `sh <script>` or `bash <script>` if one wants to run a script and terminate at some point

Comment: bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

Comment: `return` returns from the function call but does no terminate the running script code.

Answer (score 54):

Yes; you can use `return` instead of `exit`. Its main purpose is to return from a shell function, but if you use it within a `source`-d script, it returns from that script.

As [§4.1 "Bourne Shell Builtins" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) puts it:

> ```
>      return [n]
> ```
>
> Cause a shell function to exit with the return value *n*. 
>   If *n* is not supplied, the return value is the exit status of the
>   last command executed in the function. 
>   This may also be used to terminate execution of a script being executed
>   with the `.` (or `source`) builtin, returning either *n* or
>   the exit status of the last command executed within the script as the exit
>   status of the script. 
>   Any command associated with the `RETURN` trap is executed
>   before execution resumes after the function or script. 
>   The return status is non-zero if `return` is used outside a function
>   and not during the execution of a script by `.` or `source`.

Comment: `return` can ONLY be used from a function.  If you use `return` and execute it as a shell script (e.g. `sh run.sh`), bash will report an error - `return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script`

Comment: @TzungsingDavidWong: You do realize that the bulk of this answer is a quotation from the official reference manual? And that the error-message you quote agrees with this answer instead of with your claim?

Comment: l am not disagree with you. I simply want to point out that `return` won't work if the script is run as a shell script and not executed by . (or `source`).  BTW, where can I find the document about `source -d`?

Comment: There are times when I will run my scripts dotsource and other times when I will run the same scripts as a shell script. So, is there a way to detect internally to a script, whether it has been run dotsourced, or whether it has been run as a shell script? That way, I can detect how it is being invoked and handle that situation appropriately?

Comment: @YorSubs: There's no reliable way to detect that. I have some ideas for how to make a good guess, and some ideas about how the script can handle this without needing to detect that; but before I offer those ideas . . . usually, a script is intended to be run a certain way, and is written accordingly, and so that's how you run it. Can you tell me a bit about your use-case for a script that can be run in those two very different ways? (That will help me identify which of my ideas, if any, are likely to satisfy your needs.)

Comment: I have a script called `.custom` where I keep my custom profile settings (I do this specifically so that the standard profiles are not messed up and this is only called from `.bashrc` if the session is interactive). In my git project for this, I sometimes dotsource that file to intergrade into my environment, or can run it non-dotsourced. I might not be doing things in the most efficient way, but it would be useful to me (in this current situation) if I can test that inside the script.

Comment: @YorSubs: But if it sets profile settings, does that even have any effect when the script is run as a normal script?

Comment: Indeed, I think you are right, I do not need this. I guess I just need to know clearly how to exit a script without exiting the shell a) for running a bash script (in which case, use `exit`), or b) when running a dotsourced script (in which case, use `return`).

Answer (score 24):

You can add an extra exit command after the return statement/command so that it works for both, executing the script from the command line and sourcing from the terminal.

Example exit code in the script:

```
   if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
     echo "Needs at least two arguments"
     return 1 2>/dev/null
     exit 1
   fi
```

The line with the `exit` command will not be called when you source the script after the `return` command.

When you execute the script, `return` command gives an error. So, we suppress the error message by forwarding it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: this is clever. does it have a downside?

Comment: A mite too clever... would be the only downside. Someone's gonna see that and delete one or the other. Probably, me.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of running the script using `. run2.sh`, you can run it using `sh run2.sh` or `bash run2.sh`

A new sub-shell will be started, to run the script then, it will be closed at the end of the script leaving the other shell opened.

Comment: If so, then why the second parameter `sh "." run2.sh`?

Comment: @H0WARD You're right I forgot to remove the dots. I have edited the answer now.

Comment: The OP explicitly states source as a requirement.

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld Yes, but I, and many others like me, found this post because I habitually source bash scripts and was wondering why I kept killing my terminal when testing a script someone else wrote. TIL the critical difference between `source` and `sh` is shell / sub-shell.

(NB: I prefer Perl for most non-trivial scripts, hence my ignorance of this issue until now.)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I think you might be confused by how you should `run a script`.

If you use `sh` to run a script, say, `sh ./run2.sh`, even if the embedded script ends with `exit`, your terminal window will still remain.

However if you use `.` or `source`, your terminal window will exit/close as well when subscript ends.

for more detail, please refer to [What is the difference between using `sh` and `source`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786499/what-is-the-difference-between-using-sh-and-source)

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I've been using the following for years in all my scripts; works like a charm in all use cases I've encountered -- I have extensive shell scripts that are sourced at startup, plus many bash functions I regularly use. I remember trying `return` long back and having issues with it.

```bash
kill -INT $$
# Here's the definition...
# SIGINT    2   Interrupt from keyboard
```

I imagine I'll get a number of downvotes -- many folks have an issue with kill in general.

Comment: Goog idea, thank you for sharing ... the "kill" command should be called something like "sendsignal" because that's what actually does, the kill signal is just one of them, the default one but it's OK

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and from the answers above and from what I understood what worked for me ultimately was:

1. Have a shebang line that invokes the intended script, for example,

   `#!/bin/bash` uses `bash` to execute the script

I have scripts with both kinds of shebang's. Because of this, using `sh` or `.` was not reliable, as it lead to a mis-execution (like when the script bails out having run incompletely)

The answer therefore, was

2. - Make sure the script has a shebang, so that there is no doubt about its intended handler.
   - chmod the .sh file so that it can be executed. `(chmod +x file.sh)`
   - Invoke it directly without any `sh` or `.`

     `(./myscript.sh)`

Hope this helps someone with similar question or problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is just like you put a run function inside your script run2.sh.
You use exit code inside run while source your run2.sh file in the bash tty.
If the give the run function its power to exit your script and give the run2.sh
its power to exit the terminator.
Then of cuz the run function has power to exit your teminator.

```
    #! /bin/sh
    # use . run2.sh

    run()
    {
        echo "this is run"
        #return 0
        exit 0
    }

    echo "this is begin"
    run
    echo "this is end"
```

Anyway, I approve with Kaz it's a design problem.

Comment: Not clear from the text what this answer attempts to do, but it certainly does not solve the question at hand.

Comment: I don't see how this reply provides anything useful.  The OP problem was related to *sourcing* a script that uses 'exit' instead of 'return' .

Answer (score 3):

To write a script that is secure to be run as either a shell script or sourced as an rc file, the script can check and compare `$0` and `$BASH_SOURCE` and determine if `exit` can be safely used.

Here is a short code snippet for that

```
[ "X$(basename $0)" = "X$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)" ] && \
    echo "***** executing $name_src as a shell script *****" || \
    echo "..... sourcing $name_src ....."
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, even with the quirk that it returns: `basename: unknown option -- b` when sourcing. You should also address the exit and `$name_src` for completeness. An explanation that the checking is done by using s sub-shell should also be stated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this happens because you are running it on source mode
with the dot

```
. myscript.sh
```

You should run that in a subshell:

```
/full/path/to/script/myscript.sh
```

'source' http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: You don't need full path to script if `. myscript.sh` works. At most, you might need `./myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct that sourced vs. executed scripts use `return` vs. `exit` to keep the same session open, as others have noted.

Here's a related tip, if you ever want a script that should keep the session open, regardless of whether or not it's sourced.

The following example can be run directly like `foo.sh` or sourced like `. foo.sh`/`source foo.sh`. Either way it will keep the session open after "exiting". The `$@` string is passed so that the function has access to the outer script's arguments.

```
#!/bin/sh
foo(){
    read -p "Would you like to XYZ? (Y/N): " response;
    [ $response != 'y' ] && return 1;
    echo "XYZ complete (args $@).";
    return 0;
    echo "This line will never execute.";
}
foo "$@";
```

Terminal result:

> $ foo.sh
>   $ Would you like to XYZ? (Y/N): n
>   $ . foo.sh
>   $ Would you like to XYZ? (Y/N): n
>   $ |
>   (terminal window stays open and accepts additional input)

This can be useful for quickly testing script changes in a single terminal while keeping a bunch of scrap code underneath the main `exit`/`return` while you work. It could also make code more portable in a sense (if you have tons of scripts that may or may not be called in different ways), though it's much less clunky to just use `return` and `exit` where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Improved the answer of Tzunghsing, with more clear results and error re-direction, for silent usage:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -e "Testing..."

if [ "X$(basename $0 2>/dev/null)" = "X$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)" ]; then
    echo "***** You are Executing $0 in a sub-shell."
    exit 0
else
    echo "..... You are Sourcing $BASH_SOURCE in this terminal shell."
    return 0
fi

echo "This should never be seen!"
```

Or if you want to put this into a silent *function*:

```sh
function sExit() {
    # Safe Exit from script, not closing shell.
    [ "X$(basename $0 2>/dev/null)" = "X$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)" ] && exit 0 || return 0
}

...

# ..it have to be called with an error check, like this: 
sExit && return 0

echo "This should never be seen!"
```

Please note that:

- if you have enabled **errexit** in your script (`set -e`) and you `return N` with *`N != 0`*, your entire script will exit instantly. To see all your *shell settings*, use, `set -o`.
- when used in a function, the 1st `return 0` is exiting the function, and the 2nd `return 0` is exiting the script.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure to return with expected return value. Else if you use exit when you will encounter an exit it will exit from your base shell since source does not create another process (instance).

Answer (score 0):

if your terminal emulator doesn't have `-hold` you can sanitize a sourced script and hold the terminal with:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed "s/exit/return/g" script >/tmp/script
. /tmp/script
read
```

otherwise you can use `$TERM -hold -e script`

Answer (score 0):

If a command succeeded successfully, the return value will be 0. We can check its return value afterwards.

[Is there a “goto” statement in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763747/2402577)

> Here is some dirty workaround using `trap` which jumps only backwards.

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
trap 'echo "E: failed with exitcode $?" 1>&2' ERR

my_function () {
    if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "this is run"
        return 0
    else
        echo "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"
        goto trap 2> /dev/null
    fi
}

my_function
echo "Command succeeded"  # If my_function failed this line is not printed
```

---

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091823/2402577
- [How to use $? and test to check function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19442/198423)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find solution so for those who want to leave the nested script without leaving terminal window:

```
# this is just script which goes to directory if path satisfies regex
wpr(){
    leave=false
    pwd=$(pwd)
    if [[ "$pwd" =~ ddev.*web ]]; then
        # echo "your in wordpress instalation"
        wpDir=$(echo "$pwd" | grep -o  '.*\/web')
        cd $wpDir
        return
    fi
    echo 'please be in wordpress directory'
    # to leave from outside the scope
    leave=true
    return
}

wpt(){
    # nested function which returns $leave variable
    wpr
    
    # interupts the script if $leave is true
    if $leave; then
        return;
    fi
    echo 'here is the rest of the script, executes if leave is not defined'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether this is useful for you or not, but in zsh, you can exit a script, but only to the prompt if there is one, by using [parameter expansion](https://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_15.html#SEC46) on a variable that does not exist, as follows.

```
${missing_variable_ejector:?}
```

Though this does create an error message in your script, you can prevent it with something like the following.

```
{ ${missing_variable_ejector:?} } 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score -3):

1) exit 0 will come out of the script if it is successful.

2) exit 1 will come out of the script if it is a failure.

You can try these above two based on ur req.