# How to exit a function in bash

Tags: bash, function, exit

How would you exit out of a function if a condition is true without killing the whole script, just return back to before you called the function.

Example

```
# Start script
Do scripty stuff here
Ok now lets call FUNCT
FUNCT
Here is A to come back to

function FUNCT {
  if [ blah is false ]; then
    exit the function and go up to A
  else
    keep running the function
  fi
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67339783/1147688) for a clean, silent and simple exit.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Use:

```
return [n]
```

From `help return`

> **return**: return [n]
>
> ```
> Return from a shell function.
>
> Causes a function or sourced script to exit with the return value
> specified by N.  If N is omitted, the return status is that of the
> last command executed within the function or script.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns N, or failure if the shell is not executing a function or script.
> ```

Comment: Note that if you have `set -e` set at the top of your script and your `return 1` or any other number besides 0, your entire script will exit.

Comment: @YevgeniyBrikman that's only true if the error in the function is unexpected.  If the function is called using e.g. `||` then it's possible to return a nonzero code and still have the script continue to execute.

Comment: @DanPassaro Yup, there are definitely solutions possible, but I just wanted to call out that extra care needs to be taken with `set -e` and returning non-zero values, as that caught me by surprise in the past.

Answer (score 39):

Use `return` operator:

```
function FUNCT {
  if [ blah is false ]; then
    return 1 # or return 0, or even you can omit the argument.
  else
    keep running the function
  fi
}
```

Comment: Return 0 exited my terminal. Return 1 works as expected in my case.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to return from an *outer* function with an error without `exit`ing you can use this trick:

```
do-something-complex() {
  # Using `return` here would only return from `fail`, not from `do-something-complex`.
  # Using `exit` would close the entire shell.
  # So we (ab)use a different feature. :)
  fail() { : "${__fail_fast:?$1}"; }

  nested-func() {
      try-this || fail "This didn't work"
      try-that || fail "That didn't work"
  }
  nested-func
}
```

Trying it out:

```
$ do-something-complex
try-this: command not found
bash: __fail_fast: This didn't work
```

This has the added benefit/drawback that you can optionally turn off this feature: `__fail_fast=x do-something-complex`.

Note that this causes the outermost function to return 1.

Comment: Could you explain more on the inner function `fail`, what is the colon doing here?

Comment: The `:` is a built-in bash operator that is a "no-op". It evaluates the expression but doesn't do anything with it. I'm using it to do variable substitution that will fail if the variable isn't defined, which it obviously isn't.

Comment: Thanks. Could I replace the expression to some other expression to check the input parameter of `do-something-complex`?

    <code>
    checkPara () {
        if [ $1 -lt $2 ]; then echo $3; fi;
    }

    do-something-complex() {
      checkPara $# 1 "Some message here to warn user how to use the function."

      echo "yes"
    }
    </code>

I would `do-something-complex` show user some message and return immediately if there is no parameter fed to the function.

Comment: Yes you could do something like that where `checkPara` would use my `fail` function to exit the whole stack of functions.

Comment: It seems not working. (PS: `code` block does not work in comment on stackoverflow). It keeps running after `checkPara`.

Comment: `checkPara () { if [ $1 -lt $2 ]; then echo $3; else fail "The parameter isn't right"; fi; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192341/discussion-between-brook-hong-and-elliot-cameron).

Comment: This answer is sorely lacking in explanation, even after the response to "Could you explain...". It's as if Elliot doesn't want to reveal his "trick".

Comment: What's left to explain? It's a variable substitution where we expect the variable to *not* be defined.

Comment: It doesn't explain *how* variable-substitution achieves the original question's request. Why does this exit the inner function? Why *doesn't* this return from the outer function, or the script as a whole? Is this specific to bash, or is this described in the POSIX standard somewhere? So on, so forth. (Also, hello fellow El+iot+! Want in on http://ell.io? :D)

Answer (score -1):

My use case is to run the function unless it's already running. I'm doing

```
mkdir /tmp/nice_exit || return 0
```

And then at the end of the function

```
rm -rf /tmp/nice_exit
```

Comment: You might want to use `rmdir` instead of `rm -rf`. Your function will also never run anymore if an unexpected error or oversight causes it to stop without deleting that directory (function returns, program or system exits/crashes/is powered off...)

For these reasons you might want to use a lock file with flock(1) instead.

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword Yeah, it's a function that's running when a container is exiting. So I don't think all that applies. Happy to solve any issues that come up with not running, just always want to make sure it doesn't run again at the same time.