# How can I create and use a backup copy of all input args ("$@") in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, arguments

I need the ability to back up and then later use (both to read and print and to pass to another command as arguments) all input args to a bash program, but can't figure it out. Here is my attempt:

**back_up_all_input_args.sh:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

all_args1="$@"
all_args2="$(printf "%q " "$@")"

# Simulate parsing the input args here
# - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203146/4561887
shift # remove 1st arg
shift # remove 2nd arg

echo "$@"
echo "$all_args1"
echo "$all_args2"

# Do another program call with all input args here
# rg "$all_args1"  # FAILS
# rg "$all_args2"  # FAILS
```

Sample run and output:

> ```
> $ ./backup_all_input_args.sh arg1 "arg 2" "arg 3"
> arg 3
> arg1 arg 2 arg 3
> arg1 arg\ 2 arg\ 3
> ```

My first approach was to back up the arguments with `all_args1="$@"`. This fails because I lose the quotes and get `arg1 arg 2 arg 3`. My 2nd approach was to back up the arguments with `all_args2="$(printf "%q " "$@")"`. This fails because again, I lose the quotes, and it just so happens the first argument doesn't just need to be stuck together with the backslash like a file path, but rather, it is a *regular expression* argument, so it needs to remain truly unmodified. This, therefore, is not equal to the original input: `arg1 arg\ 2 arg\ 3` .

### References I've already studied to get this far

1. [How to keep quotes in Bash arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-to-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments/39463371#39463371)
2. [How can I preserve quotes in printing a bash script's arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835933/how-can-i-preserve-quotes-in-printing-a-bash-scripts-arguments/10836225#10836225)
3. [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146)

### Bash demo

Update: this Q&A, now that I have an answer, contributed to these bash demos I just wrote:

1. [back_up_all_input_args.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/back_up_all_input_args.sh)
2. [array_practice.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/array_practice.sh)
3. ...and culminated in [this rapid find-and-replace tool wrapper](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/rg_replace.sh) I wrote around Ripgrep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add parentheses and store them in an **array**. This will preserve each of the arguments as separate words and avoids all the backslash escaping complexities.

```
all_args=("$@")
```

You can then pass the arguments to another command:

```
cmd "${all_args[@]}"
```

Or print them out:

```
printf '[%s]\n' "${all_args[@]}"
```

Or assign them to another array:

```
args_copy=("${all_args[@]}")
```

You can also use `set` restore the script's original `$1`, `$2`, etc., arguments:

```
set -- "${all_args[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I credited you in this commit :) https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/commit/231c1cae164989530dfa55211698e23eb4c65d54

Comment: And [here is the culmination of what this was for: `rgr`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/rg_replace.sh) (Ripgrep Replace--allows ripgrep to find and replace on your disk). It finally works!

Comment: I've used and referenced this answer a lot since you gave it. It clarified a lot of things for me and allowed me to more-fully use bash arrays, which are extremely useful in so many cases. As a result of your answer, I've now been able to answer this as well, which I recently needed myself: [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855715/4561887). Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you so much. It's nice to hear. Cheers!