# Get the exitcode of the shell script in a "trap EXIT"

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code, bash-trap

I want to have a cleanup action in my Bash scripts, like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
trap 'echo "E: failed with exitcode $?" 1>&2' ERR

true
false
```

Using `$?` came to mind as a natural choice, but this isn't the case. It always contains `0`. Is there any way that I can "spy" on the exitcode in the `ERR` trap?

*[Update:]* I have no idea what I had tested before. This code works like a charm, so I'm leaving it here as a small and good example.

Comment: I think `$?` is correct. Your script prints `1` for me.

Comment: Hah, I know what went wrong. When I tested this feature, I wrote a one-liner and got the quoting wrong. Saying `trap "echo exiting with $?" ERR` clearly doesn't work, since the `$?` gets evaluated at the _definition_ of the `trap` action.

Comment: For anyone searching, [a similar question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32086595/471376).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your (*probably simplified*) example doesn't exhibit the problem you've mentioned:

```
+ set -eu
+ trap 'echo "E: failed with exitcode $?" 1>&2' ERR
+ true
+ false
++ echo 'E: failed with exitcode 1'
E: failed with exitcode 1
```

Chances are that the command returning `ERR` is executed in a `&&` or `||`, or subject to other conditions mentioned in the snippet below.  Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> If a *sigspec* is `ERR`, the command *arg* is executed whenever a simple
>   command has a non-zero exit status, subject to the following
>   conditions. The `ERR` trap is not executed if the failed command is part
>   of the command list immediately following an `until` or `while` keyword,
>   part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of a
>   command executed in a `&&` or `||` list, or if the command’s return status
>   is being inverted using `!`. These are the same conditions obeyed by the
>   `errexit` option.

So if you have, for example, the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
trap 'echo "E: failed with exitcode $?" 1>&2' ERR

false && true
```

Executed it wouldn't cause the *failure* to be trapped:

```
+ set -eu
+ trap 'echo "E: failed with exitcode $?" 1>&2' ERR
+ false
```

Comment: isnt that what the errtrace option can solve?