# access return code of a function from within the trap RETURN handler

Tags: bash

Within bash, how can a `RETURN` handler access the current return code?

For example

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function A() {
    function A_ret() {
        # How to access the return code here?
        echo "${FUNCNAME} ???"
    }
    trap A_ret RETURN
    echo -n "${FUNCNAME} returning code $1 ... "
    return $1
}
A 1
```

This prints

```
A returning code 1 ... A_ret ???
```

I would like it to print

```
A returning code 1 ... A_ret 1
```

How can `A_ret` access `A` return code?

Similar to [this stackoverflow question *Get the exitcode of the shell script in a “trap EXIT”*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19091498/471376).

Comment: Evaluate `$?` after you call your function within your script.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Per the title, the `RETURN` trap function, `A_ret`, needs to access the `A` return code.

Comment: Yes, I stumbled into that. Triplee straightened me out. As below, the return from `trap` will always be `0` unless there is a signal specification error. Good question.

Comment: If you are not using set -e, then the RETURN trap is called twice for a return statement, the first time, without $? set yet, and the second time with $? set according to the return statement.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `RETURN` trap executes before the `return` statement actually sets the new value of `$?`. Consider this example that sets `$?` just before the `return` statement.

```
a () {
    a_ret () {
        echo "${FUNCNAME} $?"
    }
    trap a_ret RETURN
    printf "${FUNCNAME} returning code $1 ... "
    (exit 54)
    return $1
}

a 1
```

In `bash` 3.2 and 4.3, I get as output

```
a returning code 1 ... a_ret 54
```

I'd say this is a bug to report. As a workaround, you can always use the subshell `exit` with the value you intend to return:

```
a () {
    ...
    (exit $1)
    return $1
}
```