# convert batch file to shell script file

Tags: shell

i have batch file, and i dont know about shell scripts.
Can someone please help here.

```
      @echo off
      echo "Program Name               :" %0
      rem  echo "Next param            :" %1
      echo "Next param                 :" "Username/Password"
      echo "User Id                    :" %2
      echo "User Name                  :" %3
      echo "Request ID                 :" %4
      echo "File Name                  :" %5 
      echo "Entity Name                :" %6
      echo "Email Address              :" %7
      echo "Extract ID                 :" %8
      echo "path name                  :" %9
```

`cd %9

 echo "Process Output files"
 IF NOT EXIST C:\OraOutput GOTO MAPERROR
 IF EXIST o%8.out (COPY o%8.out %5.csv) ELSE echo "Output file does not exists"
 IF EXIST %5.csv (MOVE %5.csv C:\OraOutput\%5.cvs) ELSE echo "Could not move file to   Share Drive"
 GOTO ENDPROCESS
 :MAPERROR
 echo "The Share Directory has not been mapped Contact your System Administrator"
 EXIT -1
 :ENDPROCESS
 echo "Process finished goodbye"`

Thanks.

Comment: Read any [shell tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html), try to write the script, come here with a specific question.

Comment: when I see this question, on the right side I see many similar questions that you can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming more or less Bourne compatible shell like `bash` as this is most common. To get started, here's some differences that you need understand in order to transform your batch script to Bourne style shell script:

1. The first difference is that the executed commands are by default not echoed (though you can change this).
2. Comments begin with hash character `#`.
3. `cd` and `echo` and `exit` also exists in Bourne compatible shells.
4. To test for file existence, you can use `[ -e` *file-name* `]`.
5. `IF` statement becomes `if` *condition* `; then` *true-statement* `; else` *false-statement* `; fi`
   where you can have multiple commands / statements separated by semicolons in place of *true-statement* and *false-statement*.
6. `IF EXIST o%8.out (COPY o%8.out %5.csv) ELSE echo "Output file does not exists"` in Bourne compatible shell would look like

   ```
   # I am assuming %8 means parameter 8 for the script
   if [ -e o$8.out ]; then cp o$8.out $5.csv; else echo "Output file does not exist"; fi
   ```

   or with alternative indentation (semicolon can be replaced with new line):

   ```
   if [ -e o$8.out ]; then
       cp "o$8.out" "$5.csv"
   else
       echo "Output file does not exist"
   fi
   ```

   note that we also quote the arguments to `cp` so that we can use spaces in the arguments.
7. You can get rid of the `goto` by little restructuring. You can refer to this Stack Overflow question (assuming `bash` or other Bourne shell style script dialect): [Is there a "goto" statement in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash)