# How to use goto statement in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am beginner in shell script. I don't have any idea about how to use goto statement. I am using the following code.

```
start:
echo "Main Menu"
echo "1 for Copy"
echo "2 for exit"
read NUM
case $NUM in
"1")
echo "CopyNUM"
goto start:;
"2")         
echo "Haiiii";
goto start:
*)
echo "ssss";
esac
```

Comment: http://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash

Comment: Don't use the shell for such purposes.

Comment: If you check `man bash` you will not find `goto` -- there is a reason. There is no `goto` in bash. If you want branching control, you have `loops`,  `select`, `case`, `functions` and `if then else`. Those will meet your need is a much more elegant manner. In your case above, a `select` or a `while` loop is what you want.

Comment: C shell has a goto:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, there's no `goto` in `bash` (or other POSIX-like shells) - other, more flexible flow-control constructs take its place.
Look for heading `Compound Commands` in `man bash`.

In your case, the `select` command is the right choice.
Since how to use it may not be obvious, here's something to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Main Menu"

# Define the choices to present to the user, which will be
# presented line by line, prefixed by a sequential number
# (E.g., '1) copy', ...)
choices=( 'copy' 'exit' )

# Present the choices.
# The user chooses by entering the *number* before the desired choice.
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do

  # If an invalid number was chosen, $choice will be empty.
  # Report an error and prompt again.
  [[ -n $choice ]] || { echo "Invalid choice." >&2; continue; }

  # Examine the choice.
  # Note that it is the choice string itself, not its number
  # that is reported in $choice.
  case $choice in
    copy)
      echo "Copying..."
      # Set flag here, or call function, ...
      ;;
    exit)
      echo "Exiting. "
      exit 0
  esac

  # Getting here means that a valid choice was made,
  # so break out of the select statement and continue below,
  # if desired.
  # Note that without an explicit break (or exit) statement, 
  # bash will continue to prompt.
  break

done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short example using a `select` loop to accomplish your goal. You can use a `while` loop with a custom menu if you want custom formatting, but the basic menu is what `select` was designed to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

## array of menu entries
entries=( "for Copy"
          "for exit" )

## set prompt for select menu
PS3='Selection: '

while [ "$menu" != 1 ]; do                ## outer loop redraws menu each time
    printf "\nMain Menu:\n\n"             ## heading for menu
    select choice in "${entries[@]}"; do  ## select displays choices in array
        case "$choice" in                 ## case responds to choice
            "for Copy" )
                echo "CopyNUM"
                break                     ## break returns control to outer loop
                ;;
            "for exit" )         
                echo "Haiiii, exiting"
                menu=1                    ## variable setting exit condition
                break
                ;;
            * )
                echo "ssss"
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done
done

exit 0
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash select_menu.sh

Main Menu:

1) for Copy
2) for exit
Selection: 1
CopyNUM

Main Menu:

1) for Copy
2) for exit
Selection: 3
ssss

Main Menu:

1) for Copy
2) for exit
Selection: 2
Haiiii, exiting
```