# Choose more than one option in script shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to create a menu with a script with multi choice .
like :

```
1) 

2)

3)

4)

5)
```

I can choose 1 , and 3 , and 5 in the same time .

Comment: How does the user enter his choice? `1[ENTER] 3[ENTER] 5[ENTER] run [ENTER]` or `1,3,5[ENTER]` ? Parse his response and call the correct functions.

Comment: the user can enter his choice like this : 1,2,3 [ENTER]

Answer (score 6):

`bash`'s `select` compound command doesn't *directly* support multiple choices, but you can still *base* your solution on it, taking advantage of the fact that whatever the user enters is recorded in the special `$REPLY` variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

choices=( 'one' 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' ) # sample choices
select dummy in "${choices[@]}"; do  # present numbered choices to user
  # Parse ,-separated numbers entered into an array.
  # Variable $REPLY contains whatever the user entered.
  IFS=', ' read -ra selChoices <<<"$REPLY"
  # Loop over all numbers entered.
  for choice in "${selChoices[@]}"; do
    # Validate the number entered.
    (( choice >= 1 && choice <= ${#choices[@]} )) || { echo "Invalid choice: $choice. Try again." >&2; continue 2; }
    # If valid, echo the choice and its number.
    echo "Choice #$(( ++i )): ${choices[choice-1]} ($choice)"
  done
  # All choices are valid, exit the prompt.
  break
done

echo "Done."
```

As for how the `select` command *normally* works, with a *single* selection:

- Run `man bash` and look under the heading 'Compound Commands'
- For an annotated example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182086/how-to-use-goto-statement-in-shell-script/30182532#30182532).

*This* answer implements *custom* logic as follows:

- The designated target variable of the `select` command, `dummy`, is ignored, and the `$REPLY` variable is used instead, because Bash sets it to whatever the user entered (unvalidated).
- `IFS=', ' read -ra selChoices <<<"$REPLY"` tokenizes the user-entered value:

  - It is fed via a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) (`<<<`) to the `read` command
  - using instance of commas and space (`,<space>`) as the [Internal] Field Separator (`IFS=...`)

    - Note that, as a side effect, the user could use spaces only to separate their choices.
  - and the resulting tokens are stored as elements of array (`-a`) `selChoices`; `-r` simply turns off interpretation of `\` chars. in the input
  - `for choice in "${selChoices[@]}"; do` loops over all tokens, i.e., the individual numbers the user chose.
  - `(( choice >= 1 && choice <= ${#choices[@]} )) || { echo "Invalid choice: $choice. Try again." >&2; continue 2; }` ensures that each token is valid, i.e., that it is a number between 1 and the count of choices presented.
- `echo "Choice #$(( ++i )): ${choices[choice-1]} ($choice)"` outputs each choice and choice number

  - prefixed with a running index (`i`), which is incremented (`++i`) using an [arithmetic expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith) (`$((...))`) - since a variable defaults to `0` in an arithmetic context, the first index output will be `1`;
  - followed by `${choices[choice-1]}`, i.e., the choice string indicated by the number entered, decremented by `1`, because Bash arrays are `0`-based; note how `choice` needs no `$` prefix in the array subscript, because a subscript is evaluated in an arithmetic context (as if inside `$(( ... ))`), as above.
  - terminated with `($choice)`, the chosen number in parentheses.
- `break` is needed to exit the prompt; by default, `select` will keep prompting.