# Is there goto command in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell

How to come back in for loop?I'm try to check if condition inside if. if condition is satisfied it goes to if condition.

```
    a=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

file="/data/dev-staging/Scripts.txt"
dir="/data/test"


for i in ${a[@]} do

        if [ $i = 5 ]; then


                if [ -f "$file" ]; then

                        mv $file $dir
                        continue
                fi

        else


        fi

done
```

note:- Once the file enter into if condition**(if [ -f "$file" ]; then)** then I want to come back for loop.

suppose I will use continue it goes to first if condition(if [ $i = 5 ]; then).

Comment: Possible dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash

Comment: BTW, there are unrelated bugs in this code -- consider running things through http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here.  The most important thing, though, is that your code doesn't act as a minimal, **complete, verifiable** example of the  problem you pose: To be a good question, it needs to actually show your problem when someone else runs it; pseudocode, by definition, can't be run and so doesn't meet this criteria.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or the related guide at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Charles Duffy @ thanks for the reply could you examined now.