# What could be the substitute to handle the flow control of go-to in SHELL script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, goto

We do not have any `goto` statement in bash, hence I used the below function to implement `goto` for abrupt jump in the code.

Can we handle this condition without using `jumpto` function?

Based on the solution in [this earlier answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269848/874188) I have the following code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    function jumpto
    {
        label=$1
        cmd=$(sed -n "/$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
        eval "$cmd"
        exit
    }
    start="start"
    jumpto $start
start:
while true
do
    for <condition>
     do
        #do something
        for <condition>
        do
        if <condition>
        then
        break 99
        fi
        #do something
        done
    done
 done
   #do something
   #do something 
   #do manythings
    if <condition>
    then
    #do something
    jumpto start
    else
    #do something
    fi

   for <condition>
    do
    #do something
    done
```

Comment: there is no goto statement in bash.

Comment: yes I knw, that's the reason i implemented it using jumpto function, can we do it without jumpto function by using any flow control methods.

Comment: Instead of " -----" use comment, e.g: `# do something...` Also properly indent your code.

Comment: @ghoti The code appears to be copy/pasted from one of the less popular answers there.  I don't think the OP understands how to use it, or why it isn't very popular.

Comment: guys I would be greatful if u can provide the understanding and the help, rather than discussing the copy and duplication.

Comment: Your question needs to make sense; that's why we are discussing here.  If you can clarify what you already understand, we can write answers which actually help you.  Currently, the question seems extremely cloudy to me, and has already attracted 4 close votes and 1 downvote.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use one of the other answers there?

Comment: yes, the flow of the scripts as per the new edit doesn't allows us to use any of those answers, hence i had used this option of creating a function.

Comment: That makes this an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You are asking us for help on the wrong topic. What you need to fix is the problematic program flow, rather than a way to implement something which does not exist by design. How about closing this question and [asking a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that addresses your program flow challenges? (Don't forget to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can test our answers before posting them.)

Comment: sure, @gothi will do as per ur comments.thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to extend the syntax of the shell to do

```
start:

for ...; do
    for ...; do
        ...
    done
done

if CONDITION; then
    goto start
else
    SOMETHING
fi
```

you may do

```
while true; do
    for ...; do
        for ...; do
            ...
        done
    done

    if ! CONDITION; then
        SOMETHING
        break
    fi
done
```

or

```
while true; do
    for ...; do
        for ...; do
            ...
        done
    done

    if ! CONDITION; then
        break
    fi
done

SOMETHING
```

**UPDATE**: New code in question:

```
start:
while true; do
    for ...; do
        for ...; do
            if ...; then
                break 99
            fi
            ...
        done
    done
done

...

if CONDITION; then
    SOMETHING
    goto start
else
    SOMETHING_ELSE
fi

for ...; do
    ...
done
```

To avoid a goto, this may be transformed into

```
while true; do
    while true; do
        for ...; do
            for ...; do
                if ...; then
                    break 99   # change to one less than
                               # the total depth, to not exit
                               # outermost loop
                fi
                ...
            done
        done
    done

    ...

    if ! CONDITION; then
        break
    fi

    SOMETHING
done

SOMETHING_ELSE

for ...; do
    ...
done
```

Comment: @FarhanPatel It looks like you want to use an ordinary function for that double loop.

Comment: @FarhanPatel I think you need to think a bit about the general control flow of your script.

Comment: It's the same thing, add an infinite outer loop. Break out of it on `!condition`. Change the `break 99` (in your current code example in the question) to an ordinary `break`.

Comment: In my example I have many-9nested loops and upon that condition I have to come out of several loops and hence using break 99.

Comment: @FarhanPatel Well, you know exactly how many loop levels you need to break out of, so give the exact number in the code rather than using 99.

Comment: sure will do it as per ur comments

Comment: with ur solution, it is not achieving the expected output, could u pls check once again?
It is because i need to do somethings even after infinite loop

Comment: @FarhanPatel See updated answer.

Comment: thnx, will update upon testing it in actual scenario

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to restart your script from the beginning, you can use `exec`.

```
#!/bin/bash

lots
of
code
:
if condition; then
  exec "$0" "$@"
fi
```

You could implement a crude option to skip to the label, if there is only one.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 = '--restart' ]; then
    shift
    # Skip everything in else clause
else
    lots
    more
    code
    :
fi
# :start
lots
of
code
still
:
if condition; then
  exec "$0" --restart "$@"
fi
```

Comment: that may not be start of the script, script has many lines before while loop.

Comment: If there is a single label you want to "go to" in this scenario, this may still be a viable solution.  See updated answer.