# Which command for Label on Bash and Sh

Tags: bash, label

I would like to ask about command in Bash and Sh.
On Cshell (.csh), I have use label and command "goto" as:

```
#!/bin/csh -f  

set a = 1      
goto CHECK     

CONT:   
    echo "${a}"
    exit

CHECK:
    if ( ${a} == 3 ) then
        exit
    else
        goto CONT
    endif
```

I make 2 label `CONT` and `CHECK` to separate code line.
Other example:

```
 while (${lp_ct} < ${loop})
    START_ROUND:      
        set count = 1 
        echo "===================================================="
        bjobs | grep PEND | sort
        echo "----------------------------------------------------"
        echo "-- Round ${lp_ct}/${loop}"
        set pend_s = `bjobs | grep PEND | grep -wc AL_Vcs_s`
        if (${pend_s} > 4) then
            echo "You are pending more than 4 license on AL_Vcs_s"
            goto WAIT 
        endif         
        foreach job_pend (`bjobs | grep PEND | sort -r | awk '{print $1}'`)
            bswitch AL_Vcs_s $job_pend 
            if (${count} == ${no_sw}) then
                goto WAIT                                                                                                
            else      
            @ count = ${count} + 1
            goto SWITCH
            endif     
            WAIT:     
            echo "-- Round ${lp_ct}/${loop} finished!"
            echo "-- AL_Vcs   PEND/TOTAL: `bjobs|grep PEND|grep -wc AL_Vcs`/`bjobs -u all|grep PEND|grep AL_Vcs -wc`"
            echo "-- AL_Vcs_s PEND/TOTAL: `bjobs|grep PEND|grep -wc AL_Vcs_s`/`bjobs -u all|grep PEND|grep AL_Vcs_s -wc`"
            @ lp_ct = ${lp_ct} + 1
            goto END_ROUND
            SWITCH:   
        end           
        END_ROUND:    
            sleep 6m  
    end
```

There are any command to do this task on Bash and Sh?

Thank you so much.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Bash does not have goto or same instruction. You should try function instead, I think

Comment: @Quincy: in fact this _is_ an answer: POSIX shells and Bash have no `goto`s.